# Is there an easy way to find irreducibele polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with root exp(2$\pi$ i/k)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there an easy way to find irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with roots $\exp\bigl(\frac{2\pi i}{k}\bigr)$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots,10$?

Comment: $x^k-1$ and cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: An easy way to *factorize* $x^k-1$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $x^k-1$ is not irreducible.

Comment: @TylerHolden I know that. The comment doesn't simply say "$x^k-1$".

Comment: @PedroTamaroff But the question specifically asks for irreducible such polynomials, no?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $k=1$, you get a nice irreducible polynomial: $\Phi_1(x)=x-1$. Work your way up through each value of $k$, and divide $x^k-1$ by $\Phi_n(x)$ for every $n$ that divides $k$. You'll end up with the irreducible cyclotomic polynomials this way.

You can see the idea behind the process this way: In the $k=6$ case, we want a polynomial satisfied only by *primitive* sixth roots of 1, i.e., numbers that are sixth roots of 1 without also being cube roots, or square roots, or 1 itself. Dividing $x^6-1$ by $\Phi_3(x)$, $\Phi_2(x)$ and $\Phi_1(x)$ eliminates the non-primitive roots, leaving us with an irreducible polynomial. Each number of the form $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{k})$ will be a root of precisely one of these polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ with such roots are exactly the cyclotomic polynomials, which have roots the primitive $k$th roots of unity.

[See this Link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

$$ ~\Phi_1(x) = x-1$$

$$ ~\Phi_2(x) = x+1$$

$$ \Phi_3(x) = x^2 + x + 1 $$

$$\Phi_4(x) = x^2 + 1$$

$$~\Phi_5(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1$$

$$ ~\Phi_6(x) = x^2 - x + 1$$

$$ ~\Phi_7(x) = x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$$

$$ ~\Phi_8(x) = x^4 + 1$$

$$~\Phi_9(x) = x^6 + x^3 + 1$$

$$~\Phi_{10}(x) = x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1$$